# Is there such a thing as a Windows Tool to convert LDAP to LDAPS

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap

I'm currently in the process of changing all of our companys systems that query our AD to secure LDAP connections. Our fax server unfortunately does not support LDAPS and upgrading it to a newer version is not possible due to time and money and the fact that we wouldn't take advantage of any of the new features.
So currently it communicates with our AD-Server like this:
[image]

I was wondering if there is any tool that could act as a local ldap proxy on the fax server (running Windows as OS) so that it would translate all LDAP reuqests to LDAP before they enter the companys network.
Something like this:
[image]

I haven't been able to find anything like it or maybe I was just unable to search properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tool called ldaptor which can be used as a proxy between LDAP and LDAPS.
For more information:
https://ldaptor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Take a look into chapter [ldap-proxy](https://ldaptor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/ldap-proxy.html)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Not too familiar with Python, but I'll work something out. Thanks a lot